# Cannot call jruby from a specific location

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

1. I installed `jruby-1.7.12` on my ubuntu in the `/opt/jruby-1.7.12/bin/jruby` directory, yet when I do `which jruby`, it always points towards `/usr/bin/jruby`. I tried to create a symbolic link via:

   ```
   ln -s {/opt/jruby-1.7.12/bin/jruby} {/usr/bin/jruby}
   ```

   but the output is:

   ```
   ln: creating symbolic link `{/usr/bin/jruby}': No such file or directory.
   ```

   How do I resolve this problem?
2. I downloaded and unpacked `jruby-1.7.12` via `tar zxvf` command, but when I do `jruby -v`, I always get:

   ```
   jruby 1.4.0 (ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 174) (2010-02-11 6586) (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_24) [amd64-java]
   ```

   and I was expecting it to say `1.7.12`. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @sawa I wonder the reason why the question is not related with `jruby`?

Answer (score 0):

You should point symlink with `sudo` plus you don't need to curly braces:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/jruby-1.7.12/bin/jruby /usr/bin/jruby
```

It should work.